# Does iTunes compress images that I sync to my iPhone?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, photos

When I sync a folder with iTunes to download into my iPhone, do the images get resized or compressed in anyway?  Specifically I am trying to sync large images such as 5000px x 5000px at 72dpi. If iTunes does do this is there another way to get them added to my phone without compression?

Comment: You could get a free copy of PhoneView and use it to examine the results for your particular files. I save files I don't want modified to MobileMe but you could also use DropBox or AirSharing depending on your preferences.

Comment: I tried DropBox, it doesn't seem to support images of this size.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm on PC.  It looks like PhoneView is OSX.

Comment: The PhoneView FAQ has a recommendation of a Windows version since they don't plan to make one. AirSharing might be the best bet since I just did the math on the file size - be sure it supports them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes does indeed compress large images when syncing to the first-party Photos app on an iPhone or an iPad. It calls this process "image optimization" and it even gets its own progress bar when you sync your device.

Currently, the solution is to use some other third party image vieweing app. [GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html), for example, can handle high resolution images, and there are many others.

Comment: I think the issue is that even with GoodReader the images are optimized by the iTunes sync, degrading the quality before they are even opened in the software. Unless I'm missing a piece of how GoodReader works? The app I have now is "Full-Res", which supposedly supports images this large, but after the sync optimization the images don't look right anymore, so I'm guessing GoodReader would be the same.

Comment: Syncing GoodReader via iTunes involves dragging the image files into the File Sharing section of the Apps tab. Files transferred into the phone that way aren't processed by iTunes at all and should move to the iPhone unchanged. GoodReader (as well as many other apps) also support alternative methods of file transfer, such as via wifi or special client software.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, I know you mentioned that many other apps do this as well, do you know of any that may cost less then the $5 for GoodReader?

Comment: @dpollitt A quick search brought up Files: Document Reader (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/files-document-reader/id294150896?mt=8#) which is free, can show image files and supports transferring files by wifi, iTunes File Sharing and Dropbox.

Comment: Document reader worked.  It has a maximum file size of 5000x5000px which is kind of limiting, but it is still better then the built in Photo application, thanks!